# wget through proxy in virtual box (cloudera quickstart VM - Cent OS)

Tags: virtualbox, proxy, wget, centos-6

I have installed the Cloudera Quickstart VM 5.3.0 running on virtual box for windows 7 and I would like to run a `wget` command but I have troubles with my company proxy (which needs authentification).

I know this is a common problem and there is already a lot of questions about it, which I have read, but I still can't figure why this isn't working and I hope that you could help me.

I set proxy settings in the /etc/wgetrc file :

```
https_proxy = http://myProxyServer:8080/
http_proxy = http://myProxyServer:8080/
ftp_proxy = http://myProxyServer:8080/

proxy_user = user
proxy_password = password

use_proxy = on
```

I let other lines commented.

But when I try to test a wget I got the following error :

```
$ wget http://www.debian.org/Pics/debian.png
--2015-07-16 05:36:48--  http://www.debian.org/Pics/debian.png
Resolving xxxx, ...
Connecting to xxxx... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 407 Proxy Authentication Required
2015-07-16 05:36:48 ERROR 407: Proxy Authentication Required.
```

The same error I got if I don't set user or password.

When I executed `env | grep proxy` nothing was returned so I also tried with `export http_proxy="http://user:password@myProxyServer:8080/"` and I still have the same error than above.

Note that I have special characters in my password e.g. a "&" followed by a "0", which I replaced by their hexadecimal encoding : "...%26%30..."

I can't understand why it fails after all the settings (and I'm sure there is no typos in the settings).

Any help would be highly appreciated ! :)

I don't know if this is relevant but some precisions : 
_ Cloudera Quickstart VM is build with CentOS 6.4 
_ The virtual adapter in virtual box is configured to NAT. 
_ I set the proxy in general virtual box settings and instructed firefox to use the proxy : the internet connection through firefox works.

EDIT :

As suggested I also tried with /etc/wgetrc and ~/.wgetrc but unfortunatly it still doesn't work.

And I did more research, I found that it can fail because my proxy use NTLM authentification, which is the case. 
When I run `wget http://www.debian.org/Pics/debian.png -v -d` 
I got `HTTP/1.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required Proxy-Authenticate: NEGOTIATE Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM`

According to the website I found, I should resolve my problem with ntlmaps but now my problem is that I can't install it when I run `sudo yum install ntlmaps` I have another error : (And I don't understand how in the tutorial he can install it even with the proxy problem).

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'mirrorlist.centos.org'"
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base`
```

Comment: i'm sure virtualbox isn't relevant. Setting things in the `wgetrc` file or `.wgetrc` file isn't going to set environment variables.  I haven't used the wgetrc file much but I think you've either named it wrong or put it in the wrong place or entered things wrongly in that file  http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Sample-Wgetrc.html  "Wget initialization file can reside in `/usr/local/etc/wgetrc`
## (global, for all users) or `$HOME/.wgetrc` (for a single user)."

Comment: So maybe it shouldn't be `/etc/wgetrc`  maybe it should be `/usr/local/etc/wgetrc`  But also, that aside, you can try `~/.wgetrc`  note the `.` for if putting the wgetrc in the home directory.  Though i'm also interested in wgetrc in the etc directory. If you can get that working

Comment: I tried with `/etc/wgetrc` and `~/.wgetrc` but unfortunatly it still doesn't work. I did more research and I found that it can fail because my proxy use NTLM authentification, which is the case. When I run `wget http://www.debian.org/Pics/debian.png -v -d` I got `HTTP/1.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required
Proxy-Authenticate: NEGOTIATE
Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM` I should resolve my problem with ntlmaps, but now my problem is that I can't install it when I run `sudo yum install ntlmaps` I have another error `Could not retrieve mirrorlist [...]
Couldn't resolve host 'mirrorlist.centos.org[...]`

Comment: lots of great info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125517/using-wget-against-protected-site-with-ntlm     To quote/paraphrase from it   A)wget 1.11 NTLM is broken use 1.10 if you are to use wget  B)somebody suggests -–auth-no-challenge option (wget 1.11+)  C)they say curl is better for this task `curl --anyauth --user username:password http://someserver/site`